# SimpleForm Rails: Specifying checked and unchecked value for checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I need to set a default checked/unchecked values for a checkbox using simple form in rails, let's say i have a User model who has "subscribed" attribute. So on his profile page i want to output a checkbox which will pass "Yes" value if it's checked. So far i have:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |user|
= user.input :subscribed, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: 'Do you want to subscribe?', value: "yes"
```

But it still shows 1 as a value of checkbox...

Answer (score 1):

For a boolean attribute like `:subscribed`, you really should **store the value as a boolean**. Storing `'yes'` or `'no'` is not the best idea. *My answer will reflect this better practice.*

To get a default `true` value (to have the box checked by default), you could provide a default value for the `:subscribed` attribute in the `User` model

```
after_initialize do
  subscribed = true if subscribed.nil?
end
```

This would cause the checkbox to be checked by default for users who have not explicitly unsubscribed.